# Traveling Saleperson Variation, Plotting a travel itinery

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra, traveling-salesman

Im looking for the name of a problem and an algortihm for its solution.

I have a graph of connected nodes (A..Z)  where every node is connected to every other node. I would like to plot the shortest path through these nodes that visits a given subset of nodes (A,D,K,W). The path may include nodes not in the subset ie A->C->W->D->K is acceptable. The cost of traveling between nodes is non negative, but not necessarily linear. Thus a path segment from A->B->C may be 'shorter' than A->C

I assume it is a variation of Traveling salesperson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a special name for this problem, but it is easily reduced to the original traveling salesman problem for the selected nodes.

Let the set of all nodes be `V` and the selected ones `W`. I would start by collapsing the nodes not in the `W` to get a multigraph (like a graph, but can have multiple edges between the same pair of nodes). Each edge here may be a simple one or a sequence of edges and nodes from `V\W`. To reduce it to a regular graph, we have only to pick the shortest of the edges available for each pair of nodes, since any other would clearly not be a part of the answer. Now we have to solve the resulting traveling salesman problem for the reduced graph and then reconstruct the corresponding path in the original graph -- we have written down the actual path in the original graph each edge in the reduced graph corresponds to.

Comment: Yes i think your correct. You would need to calculate the shortest path from each node in W to each other node in W. Each of these paths becomes an edge in a new graph. And you calculate the TSP solution on the new graph, then rebuild the solution to the original graph from it.

Comment: I am just a bit confused, you said nodes not in `W`. I may be wrong, if so please correct me. Would it create a problem if I collapse for "nodes not in `V`" and then later on reconstruct the paths for the original graph.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam `V` is the set of all nodes in the original graph. I don't think collapsing something that isn't in the graph in the first place would do any good, would it?

Comment: Your formulation is only equivalent to the travelling salesperson problem if intermediate cities (those not in W) are allowed to repeat in the path, which is not clear from the OP. If they are not allowed to repeat, then the problem is at least as difficult as TSP, but might be worse (i.e. it might be exponential in the size of the graph rather than the size of the selected subset of nodes).